# Modifying value of a particular tag in xml

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have an xml as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><TXNEXP FileDate="2017-05-23" FileName="/cortex/tsd/out/OPTSKRtxnexp20170523.xml" Instcode="SKR" TotNumTxns="74330">              
    <AUTHADV>
        <LOCALDATE>2017-05-22</LOCALDATE>
        <LOCALTIME>200011</LOCALTIME>
        <PAN>336890380<PAN>
    </AUTHADV>
    <AUTHREV>
        <LOCALDATE>2017-05-22</LOCALDATE>
        <LOCALTIME>200011</LOCALTIME>
        <PAN>336890380<PAN>
    </AUTHREV>
    <FINAL>
        <LOCALDATE>2017-05-22</LOCALDATE>
        <LOCALTIME>200011</LOCALTIME>
        <PAN>336890380<PAN>
    </FINAL>
   </TXNEXP>
```

Now, I am modifying the value of PAN tag and writing it back to the xml but I am not able to do so for all the PAN tags.

Here is what I am doing.

```
NodeList node = doc.getElementsByTagName("TXNEXP"); 
Element emp = null;
for (int i = 0; i < node.getLength(); i++) {
  emp = (Element) node.item(i);
  Node name = emp.getElementsByTagName("PAN").item(0).getFirstChild();
          //Modifying the tag
 }
```

From the above code only PAN under AUTHADV tag gets modified and the rest two values don't change.

How can I ensure all the PAN tags to get modified ?

Comment: Not sure if it is related but your PAN tags are missing the closing slash <PAN><PAN> to <PAN></PAN>

Comment: @atomSmasher Consider it as closed </PAN>. Lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the prettiest solution but after you fix the missing slash in the PAN closing tags this will work.

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import java.io.File;

class Extract {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            File fXmlFile = new File("data.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

            NodeList topNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("TXNEXP");
            for (int i = 0; i < topNodes.getLength(); i++) {
                NodeList middleNodes = topNodes.item(i).getChildNodes();
                for (int j = 0; j < middleNodes.getLength(); j++) {
                    try {
                       NodeList theNodes = ((Element)middleNodes.item(j)).getElementsByTagName("PAN");
                       System.out.println(theNodes.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                        if (j == 1) {
                            // modify a value                                                                                                                                                               
                            theNodes.item(0).getFirstChild().setNodeValue("4567");
                            System.out.println(theNodes.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                        }

                    } catch (ClassCastException e) {}
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
}
```

For a slightly better approach you could use XPaths.

```
import javax.xml.xpath.*;

class Extract {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            File fXmlFile = new File("data.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
            XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            NodeList nodes = (NodeList)xpath.evaluate("/TXNEXP/*/PAN", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            for (int n = 0; n < nodes.getLength(); n++) {
                System.out.println(nodes.item(n).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                if (n == 1) {
                    nodes.item(n).getFirstChild().setNodeValue("4567");
                    System.out.println(nodes.item(n).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
}
```